# create-react-app ERR! 404 Object Not Found

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I'm trying to run create-react-app (`npx create-react-app fetching-images`), it loads for a while then I get this error every time:

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Object Not Found - GET https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/cyclist/-/cyclist-1.0.1.tgz - not_found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'cyclist@https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/cyclist/-/cyclist-1.0.1.tgz' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Eric/.npm/_logs/2021-03-14T10_02_15_171Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.
```

I completely uninstalled node, npm and npx, and then reinstalled the newest version from https://nodejs.org/en/ but still get the this error. I'm on macOS(v.11.2.2), npm v.7.6.0, node v.15.11.0.

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try setting this:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org
```

Comment: This will beget another error, because TLS 1.0/1.1 are deprecated now: https://github.blog/2021-08-23-npm-registry-deprecating-tls-1-0-tls-1-1/

Comment: Also FWIW setting registry to https://registry.npmjs.org/ did not solve this for me on Ubuntu 20.04 so, still hunting

Answer (score -1):

Spent all day trying to figure this out with `npm ci` only on my UI, then tested backend and it happened there too with `pip install`. I was then prompted by docker for an update so did that, then that failed. Then docker suggested I restore to defaults. Did that and docker worked again as expected.