# While creating react app uisng npx i got following error . How can i resolve this

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npm-start, npx

Creating a new React app in /home/rajesh/Desktop/practice3/hhh.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Object Not Found - GET https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/lodash.sortby/-/lodash.sortby-4.7.0.tgz - not_found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'lodash.sortby@https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/lodash.sortby/-/lodash.sortby-4.7.0.tgz' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/rajesh/.npm/_logs/2022-01-22T11_39_41_761Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting hhh/ from /home/rajesh/Desktop/practice3
Done.

. it did't created any folder or files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [create-react-app ERR! 404 Object Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66623279/create-react-app-err-404-object-not-found)

Comment: yes it is the answer