# I am facing issue while i run npm install and npm start in React js template

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg, mern

I have downloaded a simple template from GitHub. When i tried to install npm install for node_modules it shows following errors.

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Object Not Found - GET https://skimdb.npmjs.com/yocto-queue/-/yocto-queue-0.1.0.tgz - not_found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'yocto-queue@https://skimdb.npmjs.com/yocto-queue/-/yocto-queue-0.1.0.tgz' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-24T15_02_47_113Z-debug.log
```

**

**when i write npm start following errors are showing.**

**
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'react'
Require stack:

- C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
  at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:108:19)
  at Object. (C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:43:31)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
  at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
  at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
  'C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js'
  ]
  }

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.25.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "zain",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

Comment: could you elaborate more with pictures!

Comment: @Digamber negi  I added the package.json please check...

Comment: there is something missing in `node modules` due to the way you are accessing template. Try re-installing it and make sure you are inside the folder `cd foldername` before `npm start` .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [create-react-app ERR! 404 Object Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66623279/create-react-app-err-404-object-not-found)