# Can't install packages using "npm install"

Tags: react-native

I am new to React native, javascript.
I am trying to install packages using `npm install`.
But I can't install anything. All the time I get the same error:

```
npm install @tensorflow/tfjs

npm ERR! 404 Object Not Found - GET https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/form-data/-/form-data- 
3.0.1.tgz - not_found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'form-data@https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/form-data/-/form-data-3.0.1.tgz' is 
not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [create-react-app ERR! 404 Object Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66623279/create-react-app-err-404-object-not-found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this setting :

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah so depending on your correlative, there might be somethings wrong with your node in general,

you could try using

yarn

`yarn add @tensorflow/tfjs`